# Installing MQ Messenger

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have zero experience with Websphere MQ Messenger. I need to build a .NET application that will read from an 7.1 MQ Series queue, manipulate the message and write it to another queue.

I want to try and build a POC to do this. Is it possible to install a Websphere MQ server and client on a non networked Windows 7 machine to build this POC. If so, what MQ software do I need and are their trial versions available?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install WebSphere MQ on a stand alone machine. Both queue manager and your .NET application must run on the same machine in that case. Download  WMQ v7.5 server installation from IBM site. While installing choose to install Windows Client also. Server component is installed by default. After installation use WebSphere MQ Explorer to create queue manager.  Many .NET samples are shipped with the product and you can find them in tools directory of WMQ. installation.

Comment: Thanks - I have downloaded the MQ server 7.1 because that's what I will be working with. I tried installing the MSI setup. That failed because of some missing account. Can I not use the Local System admin acccount?